# Is it possible to configure nginx serve random php versions?

Tags: php, nginx

I have an nginx with two different php-fpm versions (7.4 and 8.1).

I want to let nginx load random both php versions.

For example, at this time `info.php` is loaded with 7.4, and the other time it should show 8.1.

Is that possible to do?

Comment: I beleive You can combine `fastcgi_pass` and `upstream` features.

Comment: @RomanHocke do you please help me more? I tried adding two upstreams and adding two proxy_pass for one location, but duplicate directives cannot be executed. I'm still finding a way to do so, and I'll be glad if you help me.

Comment: I've never tried it, but I would try this: `upstream xxx { random; server unix:/...php7xxx.sock; server unix:/...php8.sock; } ... location yyy { fastcgi_pass xxx; }`